# MySql SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS disabling the order by clause

Tags: mysql, oracle, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6

I am using MySql and SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS. It seems to be disabling the order by clause.

MySql Server version: 5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (Ubuntu)

SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM (

disables the ORDER BY clause

I see it was supposed to be fixed.

Anyone have an ideal on how I can fix this issue?

Thanks Phil

http://www.michikono.com/2007/08/07/the-secret-of-sql_calc_found_rows/

Posted by Wade Bowmer on May 14 2006 11:40pm Be aware that using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and FOUND_ROWS() disables ORDER BY … LIMIT

Comment: Can we see the rest of the query??

Answer (score 0):

I did not find an answer for this issue. I just updated my select and it is not an issue for me.

I did open a bug on mysql.

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85530

Good luck. 
Phil